# Drools automatically Deleting Events from KieSession

Tags: drools, drools-fusion, drools-flow

I have a drools kiesession which has multiple entry points (20-50). I am facing an issue where at some point all the events inside that entry point are getting deleted automatically and the Fact count in the entry point is showing as 1. I want suggestions on how to debug this. Can anyone help me with this? My drools version is 7.15.Final.

Comment: Could you share some code to reproduce the issue?